# how to : iTextSharp 5.5 sign hash that was generated by Java iText 5.5

Tags: java, c#, itext

I am going to sign a PDF from the client site.
I will create a web service to generate the PDF hash using itext5.5 (Java), and then send to the client agent to sign that hash (using iTextSharp-5.5), and send back the signed hash to the web service for closing the signature state.

But the signed PDF got the following error when validate the signature:

```
Error during signature verification.  
Error encountered while BER decoding:
```

in the server side (Java):

```
ExternalDigest externalDigest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

PdfPKCS7 sign = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA1", null, externalDigest, false);

        InputStream data = appearance.getRangeStream();

        byte[] digestHash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, externalDigest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));                      

        ocsp = null;

        if (chain.length >= 2 && ocspClient != null) {
            ocsp = ocspClient.getEncoded((X509Certificate)chain[0], (X509Certificate)chain[1], null);
        }

        byte[] sh = sign.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(digestHash, signCal, ocsp, crlBytes, SIGN_TYPE);                        
        this.hash = digestHash;
        this.hashForSign = sh;
```

in C#, I using the following code to sign:

```
IExternalSignature es = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA1");

byte[] signedHash = es.Sign(hashForSign);
```

Where **this.hashForSign** is the hash generate from Java, and the **signedHash** is signed in C#.

Please help!

Best regards,
Eric

Comment: Please share an example file signed by your code to analyze how exactly your signature structure is broken.

Comment: Please check the signed PDF at  https://www.dropbox.com/s/eozsjoebv5fc2nt/test-signed.pdf?dl=0

Comment: The signature bytes in the signature container in your example PDF are not created by RSA-signing with the *C=MO,O=Macao Post and Telecommunications Bureau,OU=Government Qualified Certificate G03,OU=Terms of use at www.esigntrust.com/CPS,OU=DEPT/ORG - Direccao dos Servicos de Economia,OU=UNIT - N/A,OU=PROCUR - N/A,SERIALNUMBER=0000001762,T=Tecnico Superior Assessor,CN=Hoi Ka CHAO,E=eric@economia.gov.mo* certificate. Are you sure you use this certificate for signing in C#? Are you sure those `signedHash` bytes are transported back to Java correctly? How do you use them in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. This wasn't a Java language issue. One way to solve it is to do the following:

1. Go to the Windows Certificate Manager (certmgr.msc)
2. Try deleting all certificates under Personal
3. Recreate an ID in Adobe using Security settings.

Comment: Tried, but still same. Would you please to download my PDF to check? https://www.dropbox.com/s/eozsjoebv5fc2nt/test-signed.pdf?dl=0